# Overriding route names in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I'm trying to override the url text when I call a specific route.

Imagine I have a route such as:

```
/lessons/{n}
```

But I want to override the {n}, and present the user with just

```
/lessons
```

while calling a controller and passing it the "n" variable.

Basically, I just want to override the url text so only "/lessons" is presented on the navigation bar, while calling /lessons/{n} with my code and feeding the "n" variable to a controller.

So far I have something like:

```
Route::GET('/lessons/{n}', function ($n) {
    return redirect('/lessons',  $n);
});
Route::GET('/lessons', 'CourseNuclearController@showLessonView');
```

I've tried many other ways of doing it, but I can't seem to find one.

Is it even possible to do such a thing?

Thank you.

Comment: Switch your routes around. It will match the wildcard before it matches the non-wildcard.

Comment: I have no clue what you're talking about :)

Comment: this is wrong. `redirect('/lessons',  $n);`. this will throw an invalid HTTP status code exception. And, even though you fix the issue with routes, you can't achieve what you expect to.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your routes.

1. Order of the routes. Switch them as in the the answer.
2. `redirect('/lessons', $n);` this will throw an invalid HTTP status code exception. You can pass the lesson id using the session flash data.

So, update your routes as

```
Route::GET('/lessons/{n}', function ($n) {
    // redirect with the session data
    return redirect('/lessons')->with('lesson_id', $n);
});

Route::GET('/lessons', function () {
    // check if lesson id is present in the session
    if($lesson_id = session('lesson_id', null)) {
        dump('lesson id is ' . $lesson_id);
    } else {
        dump('view all lessons');
    }
});
```

Comment: I like the shorthand way you check for if session has lesson id in your if statement, but you may need to clarify or explain that because I think it might get lost here.

Comment: Thanks. I added some comments.

Comment: I see what you're doing. Thanks. but it's not ideal in my situation. I've come to the conclusion that it's probably bad structure / code design from my part. I'll have to reestructure it. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes. I know it is bad. Since I didn't know the business logic behind your request, I just provided a way to solve your problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
return redirect()->route('lessons', ['n' => $YOUR_VALUE]);
```

More details of redirection in Laravel can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/redirects)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. I tried many variants, and the closest solution I get throws the exception: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\CourseNuclearController::showLessonView(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected

Answer (score 0):

In a GET request, parameters (n variable) are taken from the URL. So you would need to have the parameter present in the URL for it to work.

In a POST request, you can pass the variable to the next page and retrieve it for use in the controller.

Depending on your project, you could have a button which triggers a form submission, taking the user to the next page, and hiding the n variable value in a hidden form input.